# Top Answers or Top Answerers?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stackexchange.com

Top Answers or Top Answerers?

[image]

on https://stackexchange.com/

PS: I am not sure they could be same meaning in English though.

Comment: "Top Answerers" would make more sense as the title of that section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems reasonable. The sidebar says "Top Answerers" now. Thanks.